# Comparing column values according to criteria & counting outliers

Tags: sql

I have a table (shown below) with two columns of dates. I'm trying to match year in both columns.  If the year in one column is `n`, then the code will expect the corresponding value of year in other column to be `n`, `(n - 1)`, or `(n - 2)`. For example, if a left column value 2016, its right column correspondent should be 2014, 2015, or 2016, otherwise it should be tallied it as an outlier.

```
  Date 1   |  Date 2
-----------+----------
31-10-2016 |31-10-2014    
31-10-2016 |31-10-2015  
31-10-2016 |31-10-2016  
31-10-2016 |31-10-2016  
31-10-2016 |31-10-2015  
31-10-2016 |31-10-2013  
31-10-2016 |31-10-2013
```

Comment: What is your expected output from the sample data ??

Comment: Please, add your DBMS

Comment: how you performed this any code sample ?

Comment: from above table i can see only last two value have year as 2013

Comment: so basically i should get count as 2

Comment: its oracle sql developer

Answer (score 0):

Following query will do:

```
select (case when extract(year from date2) between extract(year from date1 )-2 and extract(year from date1) then 'valid' else 'outlier' end)tagDt
from your_table
```

You just need to extract year from both date and apply normal case operation.

**Sample:**

```
select date '2016-10-31' date1, '2014-10-31' date2, extract(year from date '2016-10-31') y1, extract(year from date '2014-10-31') y2,
       (case when extract(year from date '2013-10-31') between extract(year from date '2016-10-31')-2 and extract(year from date '2016-10-31') then 'valid' else 'outlier' end)tagDt
```

**Output:**

```
"2016-10-31";"2014-10-31";2016;2014;"outlier"
```